# onChanged in livedata triggerred everytime fragment recreated

Tags: android

I use a viewmodel in a fragment and after some input, it will show a toast. But whenever I change the fragment and back to the fragment again, the toast always showed up. 
This is the obeserver and I call it in onViewCreated

```
private void overrideObserver() {
   overrideViewModel.getBaseResp().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<BaseResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(BaseResponseModel baseResponseModel) {
            Toast.makeText(context, baseResponseModel.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the function for getBaseResp in OverrideViewModel class:

```
public LiveData<BaseResponseModel> getBaseResp() {
    if(baseResp == null) {
        baseResp = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return baseResp;
}
```

Comment: because as soon as you attach the observer, you get the callback. So every time your onViewCeated is invoked, onChanged will be invoked too

Comment: @Gautam Any advice how to resolve this? I tried to put the obsever on onCreateView but it gives null exception.

Comment: @AnandaPramono you can use SingleLiveEvent for toasts and error messages